# Facebook likebox works perfectly on all browsers except Internet Explorer

Tags: facebook-likebox

I have a  Facebook likebox (http://www.luxuryprice.com/newfacebook.html) that works perfectly on all browsers but not in Internet Explorer. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <!-- … -->
</head> 

<style type='text/css'>
#fbplikebox {
  display: block;
  padding:0;z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
}
.fbplbadge {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -33px;
  width: 47px;
  background-image: url("http://www.luxuryprice.com/javascripts_l_r/images/facebook-right.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.luxuryprice.com/javascripts_l_r/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.luxuryprice.com/javascripts_l_r/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
  <script src="http://www.luxuryprice.com/javascripts_l_r/like_box.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="fbplikebox" style="display:none; background-image:url('')">
    <div class="fbplbadge" style="background-image:url('http://www.luxuryprice.com/javascripts_l_r/images/facebook-right.png');align=right"></div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/HalfticketGr?fref=ts&amp;width=290&amp;height=380&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=#fff&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false;" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" style=" border:solid; border-color:#3a93d6;overflow:hidden; width:290px; height:380px;background:#edeff4;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS (`like_box.js`):

```
(function(w2b){
     w2b(document).ready(function(){
        var $dur = "medium"; // Duration of Animation
        w2b("#fbplikebox").css({right: -296, "top" : 0 })
        w2b("#fbplikebox").hover(function () {
            w2b(this).stop().animate({
                right: 0
            }, $dur);
        }, function () {
            w2b(this).stop().animate({
                right: -296
            }, $dur);
        });
        w2b("#fbplikebox").show();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you please copy your relevant code here?

Comment: Thanks. I do not know where to insert the code. But, I am sure you can view it from my page. It is very small. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information about what you mean by "does not work perfectly in Internet Explorer".

Comment: The like box shows in the left of the screen, the button is displayed under the like box!